# Can "all" be used with both singular & plural verbs?

Tags: grammar, plural-forms

Are both sentences below correct?
1. All of the books **are** expensive.
2. All of the books **is** expensive.

Answer (score 21):

When **all** is used with a plural noun, it means *every*, and the verb agrees:

> All the **countries** **were** represented at the games.

When **all** is used with a singular noun, with or without of, it means *entire* and takes a singular verb:

> All the **country** *was* in mourning.

To use your examples, you could say "All the books are expensive" and "All the book is in Latin" (which makes sense, but isn't as good as "The entire/whole book is in Latin").