# All+plural noun. = Every+single noun?

Tags: pronouns, nouns

I was looking for the usage of "all", and came across [this thread](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/26453/can-all-be-used-with-both-singular-plural-verbs/102199#102199).
According to an answer in that thread, "all", when used with a plural noun, means "every". So, I was wondering if I could say,

"All the devices(=every device) are to be given a number."

Would it be misunderstood as those devices as a whole to be given only one number?

Thank you for any comment.

Comment: Only very slightly ambiguous, nothing to worry about in the real world. If you want to be 100% unambiguous (and a bit pedantic), you could say "Each device is to be given a number".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You sentence

> All the devices are to be given a number.

is ambiguous but most often understood to mean each device will receive a number, usually uniquely different.  If they were all given the same number then explicitly

> All the devices are to be given *the same* number.
>   All the devices are to be given *the* number: 14.