# Is the word "all" singular or plural?

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

For example, is the following sentence correct?

> All is well!

If it is correct, then it means that "all" is singular.

Then how come the phrase

> All hail Caesar

is used because it suggests that "all" is plural that's why it takes hail and not hails.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can "all" be used with both singular & plural verbs?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/26453/can-all-be-used-with-both-singular-plural-verbs)

Comment: I'm leaving this question open as the proposed duplicate doesn't answer the question about why "All hail Caesar" is grammatically correct

Answer (score 6):

I had originally provided a comment to an answer (which is now deleted) saying that *all* can be either singular or plural. But that's not really correct. As a comment, I didn't have space to explain it properly.

*All* is used along with a subject that is either singular or plural.

> I ate (**all** / most / some / part) of **the cake**.

Sometimes, *all* is used in a sentence with a subject that's considered singular, and sometimes in a sentence with a subject that's considered plural.

> That **is** all.
>   All of the cars **are** white.

According to Merriam-Webster, [*all*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/all) can be an adjective, adverb, or pronoun, and it can be used in sentences that involve singular nouns or plural nouns.

It can also be a noun itself. When it is, it's considered to be singular.

---

Whether it's used in a sentence with a singular subject or a plural subject is contextual.

> All **is** well.

Here, it's used in a singular construction. It's being used in the same sense as *everything* would be:

> Everything **is** well.

On the other hand, this would also be acceptable, if not common:

> All (of them) **are** well.

In this case (assuming *of them* is not actually present in the sentence), *all* is being used as a pronoun in place of something like:

> Things are well.
>   People are well.

Or, depending on how you look at it, it's not a pronoun but an adjective for something that simply isn't present:

> All **things** are well.
>   All **people** are well.

---

> All hail Caesar!

The verb form really has nothing to do with a singular or plural subject in this sentence.

What this sentence is actually saying is:

> All (of **you** should / must) **hail** Caesar!

While the sentence is implicitly talking about the plural *you*, *hail* is the conjugation used for *both* the singular and plural form of *you*.

Answer (score 0):

When all is used with a plural noun, it means every, and the verb agrees: All the cities were represented at the meeting. When all is used with a singular noun, with or without of, it means entire and takes a singular verb: All the city was in mourning.

Comment: I don't believe there is such a thing as *all* as a plural *noun*. When used as a [*noun*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/all#h4) I think it's singular. In the case of *all the cities*, the noun is *the cities* and *all* is an *adjective*. Which makes sense if you're able to say both *all the cities* and *all the city*.

Answer (score 0):

Is the word "all" singular or plural?   No, it isn't.   The word "all" does not have a grammatical number, which means that it does not conflict with either a singular or a plural referent.

> All is well.

In this sentence, the referent of "all" is singular.   It agrees with the form "is".   The only thing that marks grammatical number in that sentence is the verb form, so we must assume that "all" has a singular referent in this sentence.

> All are well.

In this sentence, the only thing that marks grammatical number is the verb form "are".   We must assume that "all" has a plural referent here.   Only a plural referent would agree with "are".

If the question is "how is everything?", one sensible answer is "all is well".   In this case, "all" refers to everything, which is a singular idea.   If the question question is "how is your family?", one sensible answer is "all are well".   Here, "all" refers to the members of the family, which is a plural idea.

The totality is good.   The individuals are good.   The word "all" might refer to either.

Comment: Thanks for the response. But, how do you then, explain the phrase "All hail, Caesar"? Why does it take "hail" and not "hails"?

Comment: As a command, "all, hail Caesar" shows no agreement.  Imperatives employ bare infinitive forms.  As a declarative statement, "all hail Caesar" is similar to "all are well" -- here perhaps meaning something like "all members of the population" rather than "all members of my family", but the form of the verb still establishes a plural referent.