# Should I use singual or plurar for noun after "to all"

Tags: grammaticality

I was wondering if I should use singular or plural after "to all". Instinctively I would go for plural, but when googling, the only example I found was a song title: "To all the boys", most other samples used "singular-looking words" like "To all the people". So I don't know if it's "art grammar" (like gramaticaly incorrect but OK for song writing) or just the right thing.

As far as I know, 'all' can be used for [both singular and plural forms (1st answer)](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/193125/is-the-word-all-singular-or-plural), so I don't know if I should use plural or singular in this sentence : "To all the fanboy(s) ..." and why so ?

Sorry for my English, I'm not a native, just please ask in comment if I'm unclear.

*Edit 1*

My expected full sentence would be: "To all *some_technology* fanboys, permit me to quote "...", so joking about people who defends something I disagree with.

Comment: What do you mean by ' "singular-plural" like "To all the people""   The word "people" here is a plural word.  (There is a singular noun "people" but that is not used here)

Comment: I'm unclear about this notion in English: So "people" has the same spelling for singular and plural, so "the" makes it plural form ?  Consequently, in my case, as I use "the", fanboy should be fanboy*s* ?

Comment: No, there are two senses one is the plural  "Many people" and it means "human beings" and is a plural word.  It is used as a plural of "person".  There is also a rarer sense "a people" and it means "a nation" and is singular.  This is an odd word.  It is best to imagine that there are two words with different meanings that happen to have the same spelling.  There are no other words quite like this.

Comment: OK thank you for the explanation, I shoud not have used an example that I dont "master".

Comment: So English has "person" (singular) with a regular plural "persons", and an irregular plural "people".  And another word "people" (with a different meaning) that has a regular plural "peoples"

Comment: What is this: To all_some technology fanboys....? :) What is your full sentence, please? I can make head nor tail of your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is always good to give a full sentence when you ask a question. Your examples are slightly confusing. By reading the comments I understand that you want to make sure you can use plural after *all* in

> To ***all*** (the) soccer fanboys

[NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=to%20all%20the%20%2A%2C%20to%20all%20%2A&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t2%3B%2Cto%20all%20the%20%2A%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bto%20all%20the%20world%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bto%20all%20the%20other%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bto%20all%20the%20people%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bto%20all%20the%20rest%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bto%20all%20the%20rights%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bto%20all%20the%20members%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bto%20all%20the%20privileges%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bto%20all%20the%20duties%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bto%20all%20the%20circumstances%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bto%20all%20the%20provisions%3B%2Cc0) tell you that both singular and plural nouns are commonly used after ***all***. (Note that *to all **the*** is more common than *to all* without "the").

[Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/all) describes the use of ***all*** saying

> All means ‘every one’, ‘the complete number or amount’ or ‘the whole’. We use it most often as a determiner. We can use ***a countable noun*** or ***an uncountable noun*** after it:
>
> - All my friends are away at university.
> - All information about the new product is confidential.

And you can find plenty of other examples with plurals after ***all*** on that page.

Without context, without knowing if this is some kind of dedication or part of a sentence, it is not easy to discern if *the* is needed or not. But Cambridge does give a general guideline:

> ***All with no article***
>
> When all refers to a whole class of people or things, we don’t use
> *the*:
>
> All children love stories. (i.e. every child in the world)
>
> Not:  <del>All the children love stories.</del>

If you have in mind a particular group, then you would need ***the***

> To all the soccer fanboys (here present, that attended the match, etc.)

If you rather think of fanboys as a class of people in general, you can just say

> To all soccer fanboys.

Comment: Thank you very much for scholar resources, I dont refer to Cambrige enough. Anyway, could you please adivce on the "best" way to phrase my sentence ? I've edited my question with expected output. I'd like to use some sort of formal language but with irony and a contrast with the world fanboy with is more familiar.

Comment: @May.D Not sure I understand your sentence with the "some_technology" phrase... But I  can say that "To all ... fanboys, permit me to quote ..." is grammatically correct.

Comment: It could to "to be all Plato fanboys". Sorry I'm from SO and context/conventions are quite different here. In the end, I'll go for your proposition.

Comment: What is SO? Oh I get you, Stack Overflow. Using words instead of signs can protect you from many misunderstandings :-)

Answer (score 1):

You should use the plural.  Both your examples use a plural word.

Boys is the plural of boy.  (one boy, many boys)

People is a plural of person.  (one person, many people)

As I note in a comment, "person/people" is a strange couple of words, but in this context, people is a plural noun, and functions as the plural of person.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Last detail If I may, in my example, shoud I use "to all the xxx fanboys" or "To all xxx fanboys" ? I 'd rather sound colloquial.

Comment: By xxx do you mean "xxx" or "kiss-kiss-kiss" or is there a missing word?

Comment: Anyway, it probably doesn't matter. In this context both with and without "the" seems fine to me

Comment: Oh I didnt know xxx means kiss-kiss-kiss. I was using at as replacement for a word, like "soccer fanboys/ Some Personality fanboys".

Comment: I guess both are gramatically correct, but I'm looking for "sarcasm". By the way, really sorry for the poor quality question, I'm still struggling with English subtilities and some basics like plural forms.